# Clebsch Gordan coefficients of compact quantum groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

Consider a compact quantum group $G$. Let $a, b$ and $c$ be irreducible unitary corepresentations and assume that $c$ is contained in $a \otimes b$. Let $U$ be the intertwiner from the representation Hilbert space of $c$ to the one of $a \otimes b$ and assume that $U$ is a partial isometry. By Schur's lemma $U$ is determined up to a phase factor.

> Question: Can we assume that $U$ has real (Clebsch-Gordan) coefficients?
>   If not, is there a good class of examples for which this is true? Or is it true for free orthogonal/unitary QG's?

Comment: I edited the LaTeX.   It would help if you gave a reference or brief explanation of the term "compact quantum group", to avoid confusion.